# Issue when getting value from build.properties in ICEfaces

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, icefaces, filenotfoundexception

I want to get the value of a property I added from build.properties

```
dergilik.host=http://172.171.1.155/
```

with the code below

```
private final static String PROPERTIES_FILE = "build.properties";
private final static String HOST = "dergilik.host";
private final Properties props = new Properties();

private String getHost() {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
        props.load(inp);
        return props.getProperty(HOST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }        
}
```

But the application throws FileNotFoundException when `props.load(inp);`. I also tried it with ClassLoader class and NullPointerException occured. Furthermore I changed PROPERTIES_FILE as "/ProjectName/build.properties" but it didn't work.

So how can I make the program correctly find build.properties file?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load properties file in JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar)

Comment: No, because I first tried ClassLoader way but it didn't worked as I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access in web application

- and the resource is inside web application and you have access to `ServletContext`, you should use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`.
- and the resource is outside web application, configure the path using `context-param` in web.xml and try accessing using `ServletContext.getInitParameter()`

It if is not Web application and present in the classpath use,

- `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassloader().getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: To initialize ServletContext object, do I have to Override all methods inside ServletContext. I cannot normally initialize it.

Comment: If you are having webapplication using Servlets, you can get hold of it.

Comment: It worked, the problem was not programmatical. I created a server.properties file into src and read it with ClassLoader. build.properties was outsite of the classpath. Thanks.