# Java program runs in eclipse but errors in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource

I'm working on a game in Java and it runs as expected in Eclipse but when I export it as an executable jar, I get a null pointer exception when I try to call the listFiles( ) method of the File class.  Here is the code:

```
File Buffer = new File( "Resources/SpriteSheets" );

// Count how many sprite sheets there are
m_intTotalSheetCount = Buffer.listFiles( ).length;
```

Here's the error:

```
C:\Users\Joe>java -jar C:\Users\Joe\Documents\GameDevelopment\Game1.jar
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Graphics.CSpriteSheetLoader.<init>(CSpriteSheetLoader.java:25)
        at Graphics.CScreen.<init>(CScreen.java:36)
        at game.CGame.Initialize(CGame.java:107)
        at game.CGame.run(CGame.java:157)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I looked in the jar file and there isn't even a resource folder there, so I also tried File( "SpriteSheets" ), but I got the same error

Comment: Give us a listing of `C:\Users\Joe\Resources\SpriteSheets`

Comment: I guess you are trying to load files from within the jar file:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar

Comment: I have no folder called Resources in my Joe folder.  Do you mean C:\Users\Joe\Documents\GameDevelopment\Game1.jar? Or do you mean the directory of the eclipse project?

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a file that is not inside the jar file. If you include the resources folder with the jar. In other words place it within the same directory it should work.

Ex. If the jar is in the desktop the resource files must also be on the desktop

Comment: No, I'm trying to access a file inside the jar. Is there a different syntax for that? I confirmed the file is there: http://i.imgur.com/UCKPmSj.png

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `"Resources/SpriteSheets"` directory inside Jar file

   this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()

   ClassLoader.getSystemResource
2. If the `"Resources/SpriteSheets"` directory outside the jar file

   System.getProperty("user.dir")

to get the root directory(the executable jar dir),then you can do what you want.

PS:you should check Buffer.listFiles( ) == null

Comment: Thanks, I realized yesterday that I can't make an instance of the File class with a resource inside the jar, so I just put the file outside the jar and that did the trick