# How to read a properties file inside a jar file which is inside a war file?

Tags: file-io, jar, war

I have a properties file located as below:

```
PROJECT.war/WEB-INF/lib/Utility.jar/myprops.properties
```

Is there a way to read the contents of this properties file?
All my attempts failed and I am able to read only till Utility.jar.

Comment: Check them out: [1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/APropertiesfilestoredinaJARcanbeloadedthisway.htm), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar)

Comment: @GokcenG - tried both the methods. neither worked. any specific solution to achieve this will be helpful

Comment: Do you have access to SessionContext?