# Loading Properties from a JAR file (java 1.6)

Tags: java, jar, java-6

I manually inject a properties file inside a jar.
How to load properties from a jar file before java 1.7 ?
I tried many workarounds and nothing worked so far.

There's plenty questions about it, but everything is focused on ClassLoader methods from java 1.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar

Comment: @SajanChandran No it isn't, the OP asked to not use a method of `ClassLoader`, which is wanted by the poster in your link

Comment: if you see the solution given in the question, it exactly answers the question (no usage of Classloader)

Comment: @SajanChandran A duplicate isn't marked by the answers but by the question (or did I get that wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a properties file inside your classpath or inside your jar file it becomes a resource. Any other case is a simple file.

What you need to do, before you package your jar file, is add to your classpath the folder where the properties files are (i.e myproject/src/main/resources/) then wherever you do a

```
Properties properties = new Properties(); 
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/yourPropsFileName"));
```

it will load it!

Although, if you are using an external property file you can also load it by using:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("extenalPropsFileLocation"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How java determines the path to resources? What if I put it without any directory, just raw copy paste inside of jar?

Comment: How are you creating your jar? are you using maven or similar?

Comment: No, just standard jar export. It's very simple program.

Comment: But I inject this properties file later, that's the catch. I cannot be solved like this.

Comment: I get some weird error about cannot load map$entry X_x'

Answer (score 0):

From some class, call:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/props.props")
```

Make sure that the path matches up with a classpath location.

Comment: That's what I said before. There's not such a method like getClass() in Object before java 1.7

Comment: every object has the method getClass() long before java 1.7