# Scala jar read external properties file

Tags: java, scala, maven, gradle, jar

I have written some code and exported it as a jar file. In this jar there is a file named `automation.properties` with defaults that I'm loading using

```
val automationPropertiesFileURL = getClass.getResource("/automation.properties")  
  if (automationPropertiesFileURL != null) {
    val source = Source.fromURL(automationPropertiesFileURL)
    config = new Properties()
    config.load(source.bufferedReader())
  }
```

But when this jar file gets added as a `gradle` dependency in `C:\User\abc\.gradle` and I want to read `automation.properties` from my current project, how can I override the location and read the file from my project and not from the jar file itself?

Comment: for starters, do not include the default properties file in your jar. Just make sure there is a properties file in your classpath when you use the jar.

Comment: Yes, we do have tried that too but no luck

Comment: What does it mean it gets added as a gradle dependency? Do you add this jar as a dependency to other project?

Comment: Yes, this jar is not part of my current project. it is external jar added `C:\User\<user>\.gradle` path and it pick-up relative path to that directory

Answer (score 5):

The class loader will load the file from the location it finds first.

In your case, the file exists in two places:

- Inside the current project itself
- Inside a `jar` dependency

Which file will be found by the class loader,
depends on the ordering of the "current project" and the `jar` dependency on the *classpath*.
That's what you need to review,
that's the key to loading the right file.

Your current code is correct as it is,
this is a matter of classpath configuration.

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: Through eclipse gradle plugins, `clean build`

Comment: Look into the classpath settings, and the ordering of dependencies. Make the project itself come higher than the dependencies.

Comment: I didn't get that, my all jars are inside `C:\User\abc\.gradle` directory

Comment: When you run a Java program, the list of libraries used are configured on the classpath, either on the command line or in the manifests of a jar file. For example `java -cp lib1.jar:lib2.jar com.example.MyClass`. The properties file can be present in both of these jars, but the classloader will find only the first one. By rearranging the classpath, in this example to `java -cp lib2.jar:lib1.jar com.example.MyClass` a different file will be loaded. You need to find how the classpath is set and adjust it accordingly, with the ordering that you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
Source.fromInputStream(
  getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/automation.properties")
)
```

should work.

---

### API Docs

[Source#fromInputStream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source$@fromInputStream(is:java.io.InputStream)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource)

[Class#getClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--)

[ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, but the problem here is jar is added in `C:\User\abc\.gradle` , so it always search for relative path to that directory and not from our project

Comment: If you decompile the JAR, where are the resources located?

Comment: in .jar "automation.properties" file is directly inside the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Java and so does SCALA, have different ways of reading properties file, in one of my answers I explain the difference between reading from properties file inside the Jar and properties file in a disk location.

See my answer HERE: 
[Loading Properties from a JAR file (java 1.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999277/loading-properties-from-a-jar-file-java-1-6/25999673#25999673)

This will work for JAVA and for SCALA too! (Note, for SCALA you could change basic sintax but same concept)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir, your answer is my question, I have asked same thing which unfortunately not working. `config = new Properties()
    config.load(source.bufferedReader())`

Comment: My answer says that you can load a property file from whenever you want using this (JAVA):
`Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("extenalPropsFileLocation"));`
Where "extenalPropsFileLocation" is the absolute path to your automation.properties