# How to put boolean conditions on case class fields in a config in a Spark Scala application and evaluate them at run time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, configuration, config

I have a Spark application written in Scala in which I have a Dataset[Event] where Event is a user-defined type, something like this:

`case class Event(timestamp: Long, state: String, source: String)`

which I am transforming to this:

`case class TransformedEvent(timestamp: Long, state: String, source: String, is_finished: Boolean)`

Basically, I am adding one field "is_finished" based on the other fields.

Example: is_finished = true if

```
state = "state1"
AND
source = "source1"
```

etc.

For a better explanation, here is the code:

```
val events: Dataset[Event] = getEvents()

// Here is the transformation

val transformedEvents: Dataset[TransformedEvent] = events.map(e => convert(e))

// where the convert function is something like this

def convert(event: Event): TransformedEvent = {

    val isFinished = if(event.state == "state1" && event.source = "source1")

    TransformedEvent(timestamp = event.timestamp,
                     state = event.state,
                     source = event.source,
                     is_finished = isFinished)

}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to make conditions like this
`event.state == "state1" && event.source = "source1"`
config-driven because I might have to add/delete/update these in the future and so do not want to make changes to the code and deploy each time such a scenario occurs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you gonna change the condition or config variable you will have to redeploy it anyways? right and you can keep these list in application.conf and read it from there or else what is much better you can pass it as an argument in spark-submit command

Comment: Nope, I can put the config file in HDFS and modify only that file rather than deploying the application. I want to understand how to put this in config and fetch it from there and use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala jar read external properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583510/scala-jar-read-external-properties-file)

Comment: Could you please share a snippet of your code. Especially, the piece where you are transforming and needing the make things config driven?

Comment: I know how to read a config file. What I am asking is to know how to make some of the expressions which I want to evaluate on my Spark Dataset config driven?

Comment: @venBigData I have updated the question with the code. Basically, I am just looking to have boolean conditions in my code fetched from config and evaluated at run time.