# Executing as jar says "System cannot find the properties file specified"

Tags: java, jar, properties-file

I have a gradle project with **app.properties** file present in the **src/main/resources** folder.

When i am trying to execute the project using jar, it says not able to read the app.properties file specified.

Below is the code to read the properties file :

```
  Properties properties = new Properties();  
  File file = new File("src/main/resources/app.properties");
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  properties.load(inputStream);
```

I am using below command to run the jar :

```
Java -jar App.jar
```

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: where is your properties file? in your jar file? somewhere exterior to it?

Comment: its in src.main/resources folder. In local it works fine. When i create a jar and execute it throws this exception.

Comment: that's because now you're trying to load the file from within the jar.
Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar

Comment: 'It' says *exactly* what? NB Your `src` directory won't be there at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `getSystemResourceAsStream`

```
 try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("app.properties"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, when you make that project jar, the destination of the run file is changed. My English is not good, I know but I can suggest you that:

Make :

```
File file = new File("app.properties");
```

and please be sure that, App.jar and app.properties are in the same folder.

Have a good day :)

Another solution,

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("app.properties");
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains(/* WHAT YOU WANT*/)){
               // DO THE PROCESS    
         }  
  }

 bufferedReader.close();
```

You can try this too as an alternative.

Comment: @YathishManjunath I added second solution, you can try this too.

Answer (score 0):

For someone still facing this problem:

```
public static void main(String[]  args){  
        InputStream is=MainMethod.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xy.xml");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.loadFromXML(is);
        //xy.properties or xy.xml
        String somedata = properties.getProperty("somedata");
    }
```

xy.xml should be packaged along with the jar. Its working for me in both windows and lynux server. This works for normal java program as well.