# Configuration.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

I have created a spring-boot application with a Configuration.properties file in the classpath. But when i package it and run the application I get the error - 
"Configuration.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)."
Invoked it in the following method :
    public static  Properties readProperties() throws IOException {

```
    FileReader reader=new FileReader("Configuration.properties");
    Properties p=new Properties(); 
    p.load(reader);
    return p;
```

I am new to spring,spring-boot.Is there a way to give the values inside application.properties(inside resources folder) of the spring-boot app.
Or why does the properties file I have created doesnt go into the jar(upon packaging).
Can someone please help.

Regards,
Albin

Comment: [for someone still facing this , check my answer here: Its working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922428/executing-as-jar-says-system-cannot-find-the-properties-file-specified/64279958#64279958)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the file is packaged in your jar file and is not a regular file on the file system. If you want to access a file from the classpath you should access it the following way:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream stream =
       this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Configuration.properties")) {
    properties.load(stream);
}
```

However, using Spring Boot you usually would not read a properties file directly unless you really need it for some reason. There are other mechanisms to achieve this. Have a look at the Spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).